# Is it possible to stream from the Google Chrome browser's Google Cast extension to a Roku player box?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I know that some Roku player boxes are a DLNA compatible devices, but for some reason the Google Cast extension for the Google Chrome web browser doesn't find him.

Anything I should check?

Comment: By the "google cast" extension, are you referring to the Google Chromecast extension that is designed to send to Chromecast receivers?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cast extension for the Google Chrome browser uses a fairly Google-specific protocol, not DLNA, to stream stuff to the Chromecast HDMI dongle.

Roku 3 can be a DLNA client (the "sink" or "destination" or "output device" of the video stream, not the "server" or "source"). It is NOT a client for the protocol that Google Cast uses to stream to the Chromecast dongle.

If you have video or audio files on your PC that you want to stream to the Roku 3, install or configured a DLNA server software package on your PC. I believe the latest Windows Media Player for both Windows 7 and Windows 8.x can act as a DLNA server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add the Rcast or Rokucast channel to your Roku device, then it will pop up as an available cast to device when clicking the chromecast icon.

This is for tab\screen\desktop casting.

Youtube, dailymotion and netflix can cast to a roku natively without the Roku needing to be on that specifc channel at the time.

Tip, download the roku remote chrome extensions, the remote can be edited in settings to have 3 channel shortcuts, add rcast or rokucat as one of the channel shorcuts, this way you don't have to try to get the remote away from the dog.